# TileLayerPreview:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: geoserver

I'm using Geoserver 2.13.0 created TileLayer with Point Geometry. While previewing tileLayer getting Error. Also inside gwc directory tile data is there. Everything look fine. But don't know why getting on browser console 400(Bad Request) Error.
Network Url of Bad Request Error:

> http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=CacheTestWS%3AcacheTestGeometria&style=&tilematrixset=EPSG%3A4326&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=EPSG%3A4326%3A8&TileCol=89&TileRow=77

If we see in Success request Network Request Type is coming png but in Error case showing text/html.
Below are the some of relvant images.

[image]
[image]
Any help is very appriciate.

Comment: look in the GeoServer log file to see what the error is, you may need to turn the logging level up to see anything useful.

Comment: Thanks, @IanTurton  that day After seen GeoServer Log know org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: No such style Exception is throwing because don't know still in GeoServer 2.13 issue is thereafter removing the style..still showing in TileLayers after Empty Cache.

Comment: some of those are normal I think, the client is requesting tiles outside the data extent (it shouldn't but it isn't very smart), look at the response of those failed requests to see the error message, then paste the **text** into the question not an image

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and were able to solve it following the instructions on this geoserver page

First, create the file /etc/init.d/geoserver and copy the content from this file and paste the content into it, then change the user mode .
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/geoserver
Second, create the file etc/default/geoserver and paste the following lines into it.

```
USER=<user>
GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir
GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
```

change the  with your user name and the OpenJDK with the name of the version you installed.

then to start/check status of geoserver:
sudo systemctl start geoserver
sudo systemctl status geoserver
to stop geoserver:
sudo systemctl stop geoserver
see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/linuxscript.html